# Getting TypeError: 'Index' object cannot be interpreted as an integer Error

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot a correlation graph with the dataset.I have written the following function for the same

```
def plot_corr(diabetes_df,size=11):
        corr=diabetes_df.corr()
        fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(size,size))
        ax.matshow(corr)
        plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns),corr.columns))
        plt.yticks(range(len(corr.columns),corr.columns))
```

when this gets executed
I'm thrown an error Getting `TypeError: 'Index' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` Error
after that a graph get printed with no column ways. Can anyone correct me where I went wrong. Thanks in advance

In case someone wants to review the whole code https://www.kaggle.com/code/akhilkrishnathinna/diabetes-ml-model/edit

Comment: def plot_corr(diabetes_df,size=11):
                  
        
        corr=diabetes_df.corr()
        fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(size,size))
        ax.matshow(corr)
        plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns),corr.columns))
        plt.yticks(range(len(corr.columns),corr.columns))

Comment: There's no reason to put code in comments. Your code is already in your post so I don't see what the point is of putting a big unformatted single line of jumbled up code in a follow-up comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns),corr.columns))
plt.yticks(range(len(corr.columns),corr.columns))
```

You are passing `corr.columns` as the second argument to `range`, and `range` requires integers, not an `Index` object (which is the type of `corr.columns`). You probably meant to pass `corr.columns` as the second argument to `plt.xticks` and `plt.yticks` respectively:

```
plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns)),corr.columns)
plt.yticks(range(len(corr.columns)),corr.columns)
```

A decent editor will help you avoid mistakes like this by automatically flashing the matching opening parenthesis when you type a closing parenthesis, so you can see what each function's arguments actually are.